# Assign Multiple Databases to Domain in Plesk 12.5

Tags: database, assign

We are moving sites to a server with Plesk 12.5 and are having an issue with assigning databases. On our old Plesk server we were able to assign more than one database to a domain for different applications. In Plesk 12.5 after creating 2 databases for a domain we can only assign 1 database to the site. Whenever we try to assign the other database to the site the first database is no longer assigned. The domain has been setup with our unlimited subscription so there isn't any database limits. Any ideas how we may be able to assign more than one database to the domain?